# Apart from Keras and Spacy, can I use Stanford Core NLP for Deep Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, lstm

I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis over twitter data using Deep Learning ( RNN ). I know that there are various other deep learning libraries out there like TF, keras , gensim etc., but i wanted to know if it is possible to perform deep learning using the CoreNLP Library.

https://github.com/charlescc9/deep-learning-sentiment-analysis

This person above tries to compare gensim, tensorflow and core nlp for deep learning. But there's barely any documentation and i can't understand how to run the file (or) the dependecies required . Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used RNN for the same reason before, and here is what I did:

### Getting Ready

1. Download the coreNLP package. You can do it from [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html).
2. Install [pycorenlp wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/pycorenlp/) by running `pip install pycorenlp`.
3. Install `Java>=1.8` if it isn't installed.

### Usage

Now, let's see how to use it:

1. Extract the downloaded zip file into your project's directory
2. Open the terminal and run the following:
   `java -mx5g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 10000`
3. Now, the server is running at `localhost:9000` by default. Now, you can write your program.

Here is a simple example:

```
>>> from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
>>>
>>> sentence = "NLP is great"
>>> nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
>>> res = nlp.annotate(sentence, properties={ 'annotators': 'sentiment',
...                                           'outputFormat': 'json',
...                                           'timeout': 10000,})
>>> #you can get the class by:
>>> klass = res["sentences"][0]["sentimentValue"]
```

Comment: The sentiment computed by CoreNLP (server) , is it based on RNN ?

Comment: I believe so, see the `properties` dictionary that we pass to the `nlp.annotate` method. In the `properties`, we pass `'annotators': 'sentiment'` which is the `SentimentAnnotator` class that implements Socher's RNN. See the documentation [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/sentiment.html).

Comment: Yes , this is the RNN implementation . The documentation provides a way to train the model using this command   " java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz "   . Is there a way i can use my twitter dataset to train this model ?

Comment: Set `-trainPath` to the training directory. It will load all files from that directory and train on them. And use `devPath` for the development data

Comment: what is development data ? Also thank you for answering all of my questions above . Still learning !

Comment: It's OK.. the development data is data that you need your model to tune the model's parameters and it's not included in your training.. So, you can consider it the **validation** set. However, note that these two files `train.txt` and `dev.txt` should be in PTB format. You can download an example for such dataset from [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/trainDevTestTrees_PTB.zip).